# Adding a remote switch and battery to a 9 volt dispenser

Tags: power, batteries, switches

I have an insecticide dispenser in my shop.  The unit is designed to spray a short burst of insecticide once every 8 minutes.  I have found I don't need this frequent of a burst and my thought is to add a remote switch on the battery positive lead and to relocate the battery to an area that makes changing the battery easier.
I have cut the wires for the battery connector and spliced in approximately 20 feet of cat 5 cable with a RJ-45 connector to make removing the dispenser easier.  The dispenser no longer works.  I have tested the power at the dispenser and have 9 volts.  I am wondering if I no longer have the amperage available at the control board to operate the dispenser.  I will be going outside shortly to get some pictures of the control board and how I have everything set up.  Any help I can get on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the type/specs of the battery(ies)?

Comment: 1 x Standard 9 volt battery.  Like you would use in a Smoke Detector

Comment: You probably need a thicker wire, or you might succeed with this CAT5 cable by using two pairs (4 wires) in parallel for the positive of the battery and the two other pairs for the negative.

Comment: would adding a capacitor at the circuit board end help?

Comment: If the dispenser has a motor with associated mechanics that presses the valve of an insecticide can, it must be drawing hundreds of mA for a second or so, and that would need a huge capacitor.

Comment: Like you measured 9V under no load. The power will likely drop some when the motor involved turns on. Replace the 9V with a pack of AA for better performance and longer life.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a fairly marginal design. A fresh alkaline 9V cell has an internal resistance of around 1.5-2\$\Omega\$. Cat5 is supposed to be AWG24 so a 40' loop should be around 1 \$\Omega\$.

If you parallel 4+4 as Roger C suggested in a comment that will be reduced to 0.25 \$\Omega\$. If you can measure a resistance that low then you can check it.

It's also possible the circuit would be happier with a cap like 1000uF/10V across the supply at the device end, but that would be more of a transient issue with the timer circuitry. Suggest you do both.

Comment: Sphehro is spot on. Also consider that some cheap cat5 cable can be way out of spec on some pairs. So it is not uncommon for some pairs to be a much higher resistance.